# View different images depending on what item in my list view I click

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm fairly new to Android programming and I've got this project I need to finish and I'm currently stuck.

I've got a standard listview in a Menu class with an array containing around 20 different elements. So what I want to do is load images in an imageview depending on which item in the listview I click, and since I'm a beginner the only idea I had was to make a new activity for each imageview which seems like a pretty bad way to do it since I'd need about 20-30 new activities..

To sum things up what I want is:

Code for making ONE activity that will display a different image depending on which item in the listview I click, probably pretty basic coding I want as simple solution as possible.

If possible I'm also looking for a solution that includes an SQLite database that stores the URL of an image and then display it in a single activity, also depending on which item I press in my current listview.

(I hope you understand my needs, and if you need I can also post my current code for the Menu class if it helps you help me) Or you can just show me a different way to make this work, I appreciate every answer! Thanks in advance!

**NOTE**

And please keep in mind, I'm a noob at Java and Android so keep it rather simple or at least explain what you do.

Answer (score 3):

When you click on a list item, display the image in another view in the same layout, unless you want the image to take up the entire screen real estate. If you want it in the entire screen, go to a new Activity by sending the activity an Intent.

Activities are the "controller" of your application. They interact with the visible UI and the input from the user. You don't need a separate activity for each image, just an activity that's associated with a "place" in the UI (an ImageView) where you'll display the image.

I'd start by adding the images as resources under res/drawable before going on to databases.

You *are* going to have to do most of this yourself. There really isn't any substitute for taking the time to learn Java and Android. There are several tutorials and Android University classes under the Resources tab in the Developers Guide; I suggest you do *all* of them.